# how to require a gem in rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

How do you test gem functionality? I'm trying to figure out why something isn't working the way the docs suggest, and set up my own version of [these](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/blob/master/test/shrine_test.rb). Yet my test fail:

```
19: ...
18: ...
#...etc....
5: from /Users/me/code/project/test/shrine_test.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
4: from /Users/me/code/project/test/shrine_test.rb:5:in `require'
3: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/lockbox-0.4.8/lib/lockbox.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
2: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/lockbox-0.4.8/lib/lockbox.rb:20:in `require'
1: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/lockbox-0.4.8/lib/lockbox/railtie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/lockbox-0.4.8/lib/lockbox/railtie.rb:2:in `<module:Lockbox>': uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie (NameError)
Did you mean?  Rails
```

This is my test file, **shrine_test.rb**:

```
 require "bundler/setup"
 Bundler.setup
 require "minitest/autorun"
 require "minitest/pride"
 require "lockbox" #this is the line 5 from above

 $logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(ENV["VERBOSE"] ? STDOUT : nil)
 require_relative "support/shrine"
 require_relative "support/active_record"
 Lockbox.master_key = SecureRandom.random_bytes(32)

class ShrineTest < Minitest::Test
 #tests here
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the gem in your Gemfile is in the default group (not in any `group :environment do` block), replace the `Bundler.setup` with

```
Bundler.require(:default)
```